# Avoid checking null value of intermediates objects

Tags: java

We have all seen that kind of code

```
if (myObject!= null 
  && myObject.mySubObject() != null
  && myObject.mySubObject().getSpecificValue() != null
  && !myObject.mySubObject().getSpecificValue().isEmpty()
) {
     ......
}
```

How could I write this the clean way ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this **is** the "clean way".  Welcome to Java!

Comment: [Optionals](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_optional_class.htm) are an alternative, but they need training to handle right, otherwise they are as messy as this. However, as @Jordan already noticed, this kinda is the way you do it in java...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java "?" Operator for checking null - What is it? (Not Ternary!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390141/java-operator-for-checking-null-what-is-it-not-ternary)

Comment: What if `mySubObject` is not pure and or time consuming ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074474/is-there-a-operator-for-java-to-perform-null-pointer-checking

Comment: Agreed with @Jordan, also NPE can come handy in cases where the target object are too deep level. just Use try catch block for `NullPointerException` If in `catch`, treat as `else`, otherwise, proceed using the target object in `try block` as `if block`.

It's not worth mentioning this as answer, so putting in comments only 
`try { Object o =  myObject.mySubObject().getSpecificValue(); // use o further } catch(NullPointerException npe){ // else logic can come here; }`

Comment: `Optional` is the idiomatic way to go here, in modern Java.

Comment: @Orace I hoped a nicest way would exist, what do you mean by pure / time consuming ?

Comment: @miiiii Don’t ever catch NullPointerException, ever, under any circumstances.  NullPointerException exists to expose programmer errors.  Catching it prevents mistakes from being detected.

Comment: @VGR I know. that's why said in comments that it's not good to use NPE hence not 
 considering it as answer. Just mentioned as work around (but very bad alternative).

Answer (score 6):

You can do chaining with [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html):

```
Optional.ofNullable(myObject)
  .map(o -> o.mySubObject())
  .map(so -> so.getSpecificValue())
  .map(sv -> sv.isEmpty())
  .orElse(false)
```

Or with method references even shorter (does the same):

```
Optional.ofNullable(myObject)
  .map(Foo::mySubObject)
  .map(Bar::getSpecificValue)
  .map(Baz::isEmpty)
  .orElse(false)
```

where `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` are the names of the respective classes.

Comment: Neat way of using Optionals!

Comment: You can also use method references.

Comment: Just wandering, won't it create NPE on `so.getSpecificValue()` if `o.mySubObject()` returned `null`.

Comment: @miiiii No, because `Optional#map` will only continue if the Optional is present, i.e. not empty. So this is ensured by starting with `Optional.ofNullable`. That is the whole point of the `map` method in `Optional`.

Comment: I like the way but it's still very long and not "clear", I mean it's not obvious that you're trying to check specificValue existence

Comment: @Zabuza just wrote a code in IDE and ran as I was not convinced yet. But You're right. It works as expected. I wasn't aware of this. Thanks. I wish could give upvote for your explanation. :)

Comment: That is probably the best general purpose solution for this situation that exists in Java. I personally like it, have a better suggestion? What kind of syntax would you like to have? I can not really come up with something more compact/clean.

Comment: I mean, you could always just create a little helper method to do exactly that `private static boolean doesBazExist(Foo foo)` if you really have to do this more than once.

Comment: Yup. Agreed. I must say, the way Java has implemented functional programming paradigm is much nicer than traditional Functional Languages I've explored so far. Nice to talk to you. :)

Comment: a scope?.subobject?.specificValue would be nice, what do you think ?

Comment: I see. That would be a feature integrated into the language level. Like in languages like Kotlin. So far Java does not offer anything in that direction, on a language level.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using someone else's code then you're really stuck handling for a possible `null`.  On the other hand, if **you** have control over the code base then **never return a `null` object**, and make that a rule across your entire application.

This may sound bad at first but I have developed several enterprise-level applications and this is a **very** effective way to make the code consistent and much more readable.

So, now, this

```
if (myString != null && !myString.isEmpty()) {
```

becomes simply

```
if (!myString.isEmpty()) {
```

In lue of that option use the new `Optional` feature in J8 as it is intended for that purpose.

Comment: This is the correct answer:  Do not treat null as a normal value.  Most of the time, null is not needed in complex objects, especially collection properties.